# Why is the limit supremum an increasing sequence? Is my textbook incorrect?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

My textbook defines the limit supremum and limit infimum of a sequence $(a_i)$ as

$$
b_k = \sup\{a_i : i \ge k\} \\
c_k = \inf\{a_i : i \ge k\}
$$

The book also states that $b_k \le b_{k+1}$ and $c_k \ge c_{k+1}$, but I don't understand why these inequalities are true.

Take the supremum. $b_1$ is the supremum of $a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots$. If we look at $b_2$, it's the supremum of $a_2, a_3, \cdots$. How is that $b_2 \ge b_1$? For example, if the sequence is strictly decreasing, so that $a_1 > a_2 > a_3 > \cdots$, then removing $a_1$ from the set we're taking the supremum (least upper bound) of should only make the supremum smaller, right?

The [image on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lim_sup_example_5.png) seems to bear this out, unless I'm reading it wrong. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct and the book has made some mistake: $b_k$ is a decreasing sequence and $c_k$ is an increasing sequence. Your logic is fine, but we can make things precise. I'll demonstrate this for $b_k$ (the $c_k$ case is completely analogous).

$$b_k = \sup\{a_i : i \ge k\}=\max\{a_k,\sup\{a_i : i \ge k+1\}\}\ge\sup\{a_i : i \ge k+1\}=b_{k+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is right. $b_k$ is the supremum of *more* numbers than $b_{k+1}$, hence it can hardly be smaller. So indeed we have $b_1\ge b_2\ge b_3\ge \ldots$. And likewise $c_1\le c_2\le c_3\le \ldots$